# How can I get a specific base class in inheritance?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have four classes.

`Son`, `Father`, `GrandFather`, and `GrandGrandFather`.

If in `Son` class I write `base` keyword it will reach to `GrandGrandFather` class. But how can I reach to `GrandFather` from `Son` class? What keywords is used in inheritance?

Comment: Is this really implemented in 4 different classes? Can you show the implementation? Why not have a single class with a reference to the next generation?

Comment: This seems like too abstract an example to get a useful understanding of why we use inheritance and how it works.

Comment: That is not a good inheritance hierarchy. They are all people but have a relationship with each other, this would be a better example of how to structure nodes or child/parent than inheritance.

Comment: @Sahil `base` in `Son` is `Father`. If you need to access anything upper in hierarchy using `base` then you have a serious design problem

Comment: I have the feeling that OP chose the names to make the level of inheritance clear, not really to implement it as a relation of relatives

Comment: I think he's showing how the hierarchy is, not that he created a model of a family whit inheritance. Also, why don't you use a protected method, and call it directly ? is Father method overwriting it ? It seems that there's something wronly modeled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking at it wrong. Each instance in the hierarchy is basically of the same type (for example a `Human`). Instead of inheritance you are looking at an example of composition where each `Human` hold references to other `Humans`. Something like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* Other properties */

    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public Node Child { get; set; }
}
```

Example for population:

```
Node son = new Node();
Node father = new Node { Child = son };
Node grandFather = new Node { Child = father };

son.Parent = father;
father.Parent = grandFather;
```

In general to access some depth of the hierarchy

```
node.Child.Child.Child .....
node.Parent.Parent.parent ....
```

To skip generations you can write a function such as this:

```
public Node GetAncestor(int generations)
{
    if (generations == 0)
        return this;
    return Parent?.GetAncestor(generations - 1);
}

//Will retrieve grandFather
var ancesstor = son.GetAncestor(2);
```

Comment: Why not `List<Human> Parents`!

Comment: I am sure you downvoted someone's answer, they hacked SO to identify it was you and now returning it to you. To me, this is the best answer among others. There's no reason for downvoting.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it seems like op don't want to do parent/children relationship, it was just an example hierachy.

Comment: @Gilad - Single parent is also possible. Won't `List<>` would make more sense?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I think you are right :) corrected answer

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt - True :) I did misunderstand. Corrected my answer :)

Comment: @GiladGreen much better. `GetAncestor` is brilliant.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt - Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

C# language does not provide "generation-skipping" constructs for working the inheritance hierarchy. If the hierarchy is as follows

```
GrandGrandFather
    |
    +--- GrandFather
            |
            +--- Father
                    |
                    +--- Son
```

then `Son` can access `Father` with `base`, while `Father` can access `GrandFather` and `GrandFather` can access `GrandGrandFather`.

Any generation-skipping functionality must be built into your classes explicitly. For example, if `GrandGrandFather` is to make some of its functionality available to subclasses of its subclasses, it needs to provide a protected and/or internal method for it.

Comment: if I can reach FAther From son with base keyword what keyword is used to reach GrandFather from Son?

Comment: @SahilSahilov what exactly do you want to reach? You can call non-private methods\fields belonging to any class up the hierarchy as usual, without any keywords (or you can use "this" if you'd like).

Comment: @SahilSahilov It's `base` again: it refers to the base of the class in a method of which it is used. You can't take `base` of a `base`, though, so writing `base.base.GrandGrandParentMethod()` would be incorrect.